# What IDE to use for a Bluetooth compatible application

Tags: android, windows, user-interface, plot, bluetooth

I'm transfering an existing Android app to a computer in order to avoid frustrating bluetooth firmware issues that arrise with various android versions. The requirements are bluetooth compatibility, a user interface, logging, and plotting capability to display the incoming data. I'm wondering: what IDE or even language would be best to achieve my task in the most efficient way? I'm using Windows (10) but wouldn't be opposed to Linux if it made life simpler.

Comment: `best` it is completely opinion based. There is no best.

Comment: Well what would be some of the best options

Comment: none. There are no best options. There are only which I may like, and may not like, but that is my own opinion, which is off-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay, how about some possible options that I could choose from, because the only idea I have so far is using the PyBlues extension with Python, but you might have knowledge about why you would do it another way. If I knew of all the possible solutions and was asking "what do you think is the best" then you're right, but I simply do not know where to start so I'm asking for your input.

Comment: Can't you understand that you should not ask opinion-based questions here? Same thing as I shouldn't answer such questions. i can't suggest anything opinion-based, sorry.